# PostgreSQL Foreign Key and Child Tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, single-table-inheritance, postgresql-9.3

I have the following tables:

```
--Competition tables
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tr.Competitions(
    competition_id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    competition_name    text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tr.CompetitionsQuestions(
    competition_id      int NOT NULL,
    question_id         int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (competition_id) REFERENCES Tr.Competitions(competition_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES Tr.Questions(question_id)
);

--Questions tables
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tr.Questions(
    question_id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question_text       text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tr.MultiQuestions(
    possible_answers    text ARRAY NOT NULL,
    correct_answer      int NOT NULL
) INHERITS(Tr.Questions);
```

I try to insert some dummy data into Tr.CompetitionQuestions like so:

```
--Test Fixtures
INSERT INTO Tr.MultiQuestions (question_text, possible_answers, correct_answer) 
    VALUES ('Which of the following is awesome?', '{"Indian Food","Soccer","All the above"}', 2);

INSERT INTO Tr.Competitions(competition_name)
    VALUES ('Awesome Competition');

INSERT INTO Tr.CompetitionsQuestions(competition_id, question_id) 
    VALUES ((SELECT competition_id FROM Tr.Competitions WHERE competition_id=1),
            (SELECT question_id FROM Tr.Questions WHERE question_id=1));
```

Having these stored in an .sql file and running `\i some.sql` is gerenating the following error. How do I add a question foreign key to the CompetitionsQuestions table?

```
 ERROR:  insert or update on table "competitionsquestions" violates foreign key constraint "competitionsquestions_question_id_fkey"      
DETAIL:  Key (question_id)=(1) is not present in table "questions".
```

Seems like a weird error since `SELECT * FROM tr.questions WHERE question_id=1` actually gives me the stored multiquestion row.

EDIT:

Simplifying to:

```
INSERT INTO Tr.CompetitionsQuestions(competition_id, question_id) 
    VALUES (1, 1);
```

gives me the same error;

Comment: where do you insert into `Tr.Questions`?

Comment: I insert into `Tr.MultiQuestions` which inherits from `Tr.Questions`. There are other questions types (not shown) such as `Tr.TrueFalse` `Tr.ShortAnswer` which also inherit from `Tr.Questions`

Comment: My intention was to allow the use any type of Question as the FK in the CompetitionsQuestions table

Comment: `select * from questions` is equivalent to `select * from questions*` and selects from `questions` and all its children, which is why you're seeing question_id 1. `select * from only questions` will probably not return any results, which is where postgres is trying to satisfy the fk requirement. you may need to use a 3rd table and triggers to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok will look into that.

Comment: Your DDL is incomplete. You don't show any inheritance anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming, from comments, that you're using PostgreSQL's table inheritance features, since your question doesn't really contain full info about the schema and how you populate its contents):

Foreign keys don't apply across all members of an inheritance tree. They can only be to the *specific* table.

The same is true of a `UNIQUE` constraint or `PRIMARY KEY`.

You can see what a foreign key constraint will see in a table if you:

```
 SELECT * FROM ONLY thetable;
```

The `ONLY` keyword tells PostgreSQL not to include child tables. That's what's used in foreign key constraint checks.